# SQL stored proc max date issue

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, maxdate

I have a issue with getting the MAX DATE from a stored procedure.

Basically, I have a list of exchange rates with date of capture, which are captured daily stored within a table and I wish to return the latest value.

Here is the code I am working on..

```
select  
distinct t.source_currency_code, t.target_currency_code,
'(' + t.source_currency_code + ') '  + s.currency_name as source_currency_name, 
'(' + t.target_currency_code + ') '  + x.currency_name as target_currency_name,
t.converted_amount as buy_rate,
t.date_loaded as date_loaded

from texchange_rate t, tcurrency s, tcurrency x

where 
s.currency_code = t.source_currency_code and 
x.currency_code = t.target_currency_code

order by  t.source_currency_code
```

My thought was to MAX(.t.date_loaded grouped by currency_code) but that does not work...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from 
(select t.source_currency_code, 
        t.target_currency_code,
        '('+t.source_currency_code+') '  + s.currency_name as source_currency_name, 
        '('+t.target_currency_code+') '  + x.currency_name as target_currency_name,
        t.converted_amount as buy_rate,
        t.date_loaded as date_loaded,
        rank() over (partition by t.source_currency_code, 
                                  t.target_currency_code 
                     order by t.date_loaded desc) rn
 from texchange_rate t
 join tcurrency s on s.currency_code = t.source_currency_code 
 join tcurrency x on x.currency_code = t.target_currency_code) v
where rn = 1
order by source_currency_code, target_currency_code
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have source & target currency as elements to lookup your latest buying rate.

could you get along with this ?

```
 SELECT
t.source_currency_code, t.target_currency_code,
'(' + t.source_currency_code + ') '  + s.currency_name as source_currency_name, 
'(' + t.target_currency_code + ') '  + x.currency_name as target_currency_name,
t.converted_amount as buy_rate,
t.date_loaded as date_loaded
FROM 
texchange_rate t
INNER JOIN tcurrency s
ON t.source_currency_code = s.currency_code
INNER JOIN tcurrency x
ON t.target_currency_code = x.currency_code
WHERE t.date_loaded in 
      (
          SELECT max(date_loaded) from texchange_rate tt
          where t.source_currency_code = tt.source_currency_code
          and t.target_currency_code = tt.target_currency_code
      )
order by date_loaded desc
```

**UPDATE**
remove the distinct and group by currency code, I'm thinking order by date_loaded would give you latest values not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Hmm, trying that. Getting an error "Column 'texchange_rate.target_currency_code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: The WHERE query worked, I can't post my answer yet though for another 7 hours! :(
Thanks so much for your hlep.